# Parallel transport for a conformally equivalent metric

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, conformal-geometry

Suppose $M$ is a smooth manifold equipped with a Riemannian metric $g$. Given a curve $c$, let $P_c$ denote parallel transport along $c$. Now suppose you consider a new metric $g'=fg$ where $f$ is a smooth positive function. Let $P_c'$ denote parallel transport along $c$ with respect to $g'$. How are $P_c$ and $P_c$ related?

A similar question is: let $K:TTM \rightarrow TM$ denote the *connection map* associated to $g$ and $K'$ the one associated to $g'$. How are $K$ and $K'$ related?

In case it's helpful, recall the definition of $K$: given $V\in T_{(x,v)}TM$, let $z(t)=(c(t),v(t))$
be a curve in $TM$ such that $z(0)=(x,v)$ and $\dot{z}(0)=V$. Then set 
$$K(V):=\nabla_{t}v(0).$$

Answer (score 1):

Both the parallel transport and the connection map are determined by the connection, in your case this is the Levi-Civita connection of metric $g$ whose transformation is known (see e.g. [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/98113/) answer).

For the connection map you already have a formula in the definition, just use the facts and get the expression.

With regards to the parallel transport I guess the best way would be to start with the equations
$$
\dot{V}^{k}(t)= - V^{j}(t)\dot{c}^{i}(t)\Gamma^{k}_{ij}(c(t))
$$
that describe the parallel transport (see the details e.g. in J.Lee's "[Riemannian manifolds. An Introduction to Curvature](http://books.google.co.nz/books/?id=ZRQgH7FQafgC)").

The Christoffel symbols of the conformally rescaled metric are given in [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_formulas_in_Riemannian_geometry#Under_a_conformal_change) Wikipedia article. Using them we get the equations of the conformally related parallel transport.

Comment: See also [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/124523/2002) answer.