# Books and references for Conformal Differential Geometry

Tags: differential-geometry, book-recommendation, conformal-geometry

In this semester I want to study Conformal Differential Geometry, but I don't know which book is suitable as a textbook or reference.

Can people recommend textbooks and/or other references to me? If there are some online videos for the lecture, it would be more friendly to me.

Comment: Please take a look at [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/761396/2002). You may find the bibliography list in my thesis useful too (see the link in [my profile](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/2002/yuri-vyatkin?tab=profile)).

Comment: Thank you. It is useful to me the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend starting with an inspirational lecture of **Charles Fefferman** on Conformal Invariants on [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AnjF72ED-m0).

Next, one can brush up the necessary basics by reading wonderful lectures notes of **Jeff A. Viaclovsky** [Math 865, Topics in Riemannian Geometry](https://www.math.uci.edu/%7Ejviaclov/courses/865_Fall_2007.pdf).

To get the taste of the modern conformal differential geometry, you should try to read **Michael Eastwood**'s [Notes on conformal differential geometry](https://dml.cz/handle/10338.dmlcz/701576). This is not easy reading, though. You will have a lot of questions, that you may need to ask either [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/) or on even on [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/).

To make more sense of Eastwood's notes, it would be helpful to give a good read to [An introduction to conformal geometry and tractor calculus, with a view to applications in general relativity](https://arxiv.org/abs/1412.7559) by **Sean Curry** and **A. Rod Gover**.

From this video recording of **A. Rod Gover**' talk [Boundary operators on conformally compact manifolds, and a boundary Loewner-Niremberg-Yamabe problem](http://www.birs.ca/events/2014/5-day-workshops/14w5105/videos/watch/201411041602-Gover.html) you can get an idea of what the latest results in conformal differential geometry are about.

This list is biased, incomplete, opinionated, based on my personal experience, and may be misleading and outdated, so please beware of the risks.