# What is $\frac{1}{\omega_n}\displaystyle\int_{\mathbb{S}^n}\! x_{n+1}^2\,\mathrm{d}x$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I wish to calculate the integral $$I=\frac{1}{\omega_n}\int_{\mathbb{S}^n}\! x_{n+1}^2\,\mathrm{d}x$$ where $\mathbb{S}^{n}$ denotes the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ with surface area $\omega_n$, and $\mathrm{d}x$ denotes integration w.r.t. the usual measure on $\mathbb{S}^{n}$, and in a slight abuse of notation, $x_{n+1}$ refers to the coordinate in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$. This is my approach as a solution.

We may rewrite this integral in stereographic coordinates ([see my previous question for the relevant formulae](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2179547/riemann-curvature-tensor-of-mathbbs-rn-with-stereographic-projection)) as 
$$
 I= \frac{1}{\omega_n}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\,\left(\frac{2y_i}{1+|y|^2}\right)^2\frac{2^n}{(1+|y|^2)^n}\,\mathrm{d}y = \frac{1}{\omega_n}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\,\frac{2^{n+2} y_i^2}{(1+|y|^2)^{n+2}}\,\mathrm{d}y
$$
but then
\begin{align}
nI &= \frac{1}{\omega_n}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\,\frac{2^{n+2}|y|^2}{(1+|y|^2)^{n+2}}\,\mathrm{d}y
= 2^{n+2}\frac{\omega_{n-1}}{\omega_n}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\,\frac{r^{n+1}}{(1+r^2)^{n+2}}\,\mathrm{d}y \\
&= 2^{n+1}\frac{\omega_{n-1}}{\omega_n} \int_0^\infty{\frac{s^{\frac n2}}{(1+s)^{n+2}}}\,\mathrm{d}s \tag*{ $r^2=s$ } \\
&= 2^{n+1}\frac{\omega_{n-1}}{\omega_n}\int_0^1 \left(\frac{1-t}{t}\right)^{\frac n2}t^n\,\mathrm{d}t \tag*{ $ t=1/(1+s) $ } \\
&= 2^{n+1}\frac{\omega_{n-1}}{\omega_n} B\left(\frac n2+1,\frac n2+1\right) \\
&= 2^{n+1}\frac{\omega_{n-1}}{\omega_n}\frac{\Gamma(\tfrac n2 + 1)^2}{\Gamma(n+2)}
\end{align}
where $B$ is the beta function, so that
$$
\frac{1}{\omega_n}\int_{\mathbb{S}^n}\! x_{n+1}^2\,\mathrm{d}x = 
\frac{2^{n+1}\omega_{n-1}\Gamma(\tfrac n2 + 1)^2}{n \omega_n\Gamma(n+2)}.
$$

This seems awfully complicated. Is there any way to get a simpler answer to this? Expanding out $\omega_{n-1}$ and $\omega_n$ doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes! The fact that's it's $x_{n+1}$ is not important: by applying rotations to the coordinates, we find that
$$ \int_{S^n} x_1^2 \, dx = \int_{S^n} x_2^2 \, dx = \dotsb = \int_{S^n} x_{n+1}^2 \, dx. $$
Adding all $n+1$ of these together gives
$$ (n+1)\int_{S^n} x_{n+1}^2 \, dx = \int_{S^n} (x_1^2+x_2^2+\dotsb+x_{n+1}^2) \, dx = \int_{S^n} \, dx = \omega_n, $$
since the sum of the squares of the coordinates is $1$ on the unit sphere. Hence
$$ \frac{1}{\omega_n}\int_{S^n} x_{n+1}^2 \, dx = \frac{1}{n+1}. $$

Comment: Never before have I wasted so much effort on a result so simple... thanks for the answer though.

Comment: Happens to all of us :)

Comment: Conversely, is there anything we can say about
$$
\frac{1}{\omega_n}\int_{S^n} f(x_1^2,\ldots,x_{n+1}^2)\, dx
$$ for a polynomial $f$?

Comment: Probably very little, unfortunately. One can replace the $x_{n+1}^2$ with $1-\sum_{i=1}^n x_{i}^2$ (or one of the others if more suitable), and then the terms collect into various types depending on the various powers involved. It's also $1/n!$ of $\int_{S^n} \sum_{\sigma \in S_n} f(x_{\sigma(1)}^2,\dotsc,x_{\sigma(n+1)}^2) \, dx $, which is symmetric and so can be written in terms of the elementary symmetric polynomials, but  $\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} x_i^2=1 $ is the only relation between the coordinates, so that may not be that much help. Probably worth asking a separate question.